# Removing joins to layers using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins

I have some layers that point to feature classes in a geodatabase. Some of the layers are joined to a table also in the geodatabase and I am trying to remove all the joins so that I can run some other operations in Python but arcpy.management.RemoveJoin(in_layer_or_view, {join_name}) doesn't seem to be doing anything. Here is a simplified version of my script.

```
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")

current_map = aprx.listMaps('*')[0]

for lyr in current_map.listLayers():

    arcpy.AddMessage(f"LAYER {lyr.name}")

    arcpy.management.RemoveJoin(lyr)

    arcpy.AddMessage("Join Removed")

aprx.save()
```

The script spits out the message "Join Removed" for every layer (even the layers without joins) but doesn't actually do anything. I have tried putting in lyr.name for the first argument but that doesn't change anything. I also found a subroutine to get the names of the joins which works so I tried to put those into the second optional argument just to try and force it to do something but I get the same behavior. The script runs completely with no errors but the joins remain.

Am I missing something?

EDIT:
I am having a similar issue when I try to add joins with arcpy.management.AddJoin(). After running the script the joins do not show up in the the layers in ArcGIS Pro.

After some experimentation I printed out the field names for every layer and found that the joined fields do get printed out so the join is working temporarily, however it is not being applied to the actual map after the script runs. I have done an aprx.save() but is there some other method to actually save those changes?

Comment: If you do an aprx.save(), close and re-open your project in ArcGIS Pro are the joins there?

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. The joins are still there.

Comment: Does your Project have multiple maps because the code you show only removes the joins in the first map. @PolyGeo is right to say you need to save your project after you break the join(s) to actually persist what you have done.

Comment: The project only has one map. I added aprx.save() at the bottom of my script and I get the same behavior.

Comment: Have you tried adding in the join name? I know the documentation says it is optional but the documentation is not always correct and the join name parameter might actually be required.